# № в техническом тексте

Tags: грамотная-речь

Вопрос следующий:
как правильно говорить "Палата №.. хирургического отделения" или "Палата хирургического отделения №..", если речь идет о номере палаты?
Также "Стоянка №.. торгового центра" или "Стоянка торгового центра №..", если речь о номере стоянки. И прочие подобные случаи.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В техническом тексте выбор всегда в пользу однозначности понимания (палата №..., стоянка №...). Если вы возьмёте описание  к любому патенту, при описании схемы даже может показаться непривычной нумерация всех элементов сразу после указания видового понятия (блок 4 корректоров кабеля и т.п.).

Answer (score 1):

Такие вещи ничем и никем не нормируется. Оба варианта правильны Но логичнее выглядит первый вариант, во втором случае возможна явная двусмысленность.

Палата № 6 - или отделение № 6?
Стоянка №... - или ТЦ №...

В случае *"Палата №.. хирургического отделения" - "Стоянка №.. торгового центра"*

Но, если контекст исключает подобную двусмысленность, и другой вариант может быть возможен.